Can Angular 1.4.x legacy app be embedded in Springboot 3.4.0 with Dynamic web app 6.0 config for tomcat 10.1 or which version of dynamic web will work
I have a spring 4.2.5 app with embedded angular JS v1.4.x now I am revamping the Java code from Java 8 to Java 21 and tomcat 9 to tomcat 10.1.the UI will have it redeveloped in react later. But for now I wish to retain the Angular JS 1.4.x and this is a spring boot 3.4.0 app now with dynamic web project 6.0 setting. I had hard time using the webapp folder structure to make spring find the index.html to load angular scripts. I did make changes to have static, assets folder structure and removed web.xml and moved to more modern architecture but angular js 1.4.x isnt loading some js and css files.even html in WEB-INF folder. wish to know what is the middle ground here should I move to previous versions of Dynamic web project or it can be made to work.  Has anybody had this issue before.
I need Spring boot web 3.4.0 with spring security be able to work with previously working embedded Angular JS 1.4.x project with dynamic web 6.0 setting or any middle ground that will work. I cannot redevelop the Angular JS code as there is a replacement Web UI project already on the anvil.

Why couldn't it? It is "just a front-end framework" and issues HTTP requests. What is consuming those requests doesn't matter.
